# how to run next js project in vs code?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am doing a next js project with my friend. I want to run the project with vs code but when i run the commmand "yarn start", i get the following error:

There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed in your site's "node_modules" directory. Perhaps you
need to run "npm install"? You might need to delete your "package-lock.json" as well.

error Command failed with exit code 1.

I have done every thing to solve the problem but it is still there.I have re installed npm and gatsby.I have node installed but the problem is still there.I dont know how to fix it.Please guide me

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before `npm start`?

Comment: have you tried running `npm i && npx next dev` in your terminal?

Comment: Hold up a second; you say that you are doing a nextjs project but the error says something about Gatsby; which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to delete the package-lock.json then navigate to the root folder of the project and run in the terminal "npm i", also make sure that You have created the nextjs project as in the guidance here -> https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app